# Losing scroll of Text View when using setOnTouchListener?

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

I use code like this to detect swipe left or right.

```
TextView lastTV= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastTvValue);

lastTV.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //do stuff here
                }

            Log.i("click text", "kakak");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But I loss scroll on TextView when I apply it to my code.

Answer (score 0):

One solution, not tested:

Replace the TextView for a custom view:

```
package view;
public SwypeTextView extends TextView {
     public SwypeTextView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) { super(ctx, attrs); }
     @Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //do stuff here
            }
            return super.onTouchEvent(evt);
     }
}
```

Not tested but should work.

If using trough XML declare view.SwypeTextView.
If using by code you can simple extends the TextView and override onTouchEvent by the way.